# VBA for filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop each visible cell after filtering for #N/A, and inserting an index match formula. However the For Each cell loop stops halfway. For context there are 180 counts of rows after filtering, and for some reason my loop stops at R180 when there are more rows to 217.

```
'Filter for #N/A after PO lookup
Dim LastCellFilteredPO As Range
Set LastCellFilteredPO = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)
Worksheets("sheet1").rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("sheet1").rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:" & LastCellFilteredPO.Address).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="#N/A"

'Indexmatch for WBSGL

Dim lookupcell As Range
Dim Cellcount As Integer
Cellcount = 0

With Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R2:" & LastCellFilteredPO.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Cellcount = Cellcount + 1
        Set lookupcell = Range("Q" & .Offset(Cellcount, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row)
        Range("R" & .Offset(Cellcount, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value = "=INDEX('[" & DVOFileName & "]WBSGL accounts'!$B:$B,MATCH(" & lookupcell.Address & ",'[" & DVOFileName & "]WBSGL accounts'!$A:$A,0))"
    Next cell
    
End With
```

After looping, all cell formulas work fine but the loop stops at cell R180. The lastcellfiltered is 217.

Comment: You can check again if the entire data comes in the AutoFilter range. Sometimes it can skip rows from the bottom if they are not in continuity or data is missing in between.

Comment: Try changing the line to:
`For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Autofilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Could you share a few results i.e. if e.g. rows `R3`, `R4`, and `R6` are visible, what (the formulas in A1-style (the lookup cell address)) needs to be written and where (`Q3`, `Q4`, and `Q6`?)?

Answer (score 2):

### Write Index/Match Formula to a Discontinuous Column

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MatchData()
    
    Dim DVOFileName As String: DVOFileName = "Equalizer 3.xlsx" ' ?

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    trg.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    
    Dim frg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = trg.Columns(18).Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1) _
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If frg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fFormula As String: fFormula = "=INDEX('[" & DVOFileName _
        & "]WBSGL accounts'!$B:$B,MATCH(" _
        & frg.Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns("Q").Address(0, 0) _
        & ",'[" & DVOFileName & "]WBSGL accounts'!$A:$A,0))"
    
    frg.Formula = fFormula
    
    MsgBox "Formulas written.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `.Offset(Cellcount, 0)` is applied to the unfiltered range so the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row` stays the same until the cellcount equals the next filtered row. Effectively writing to the same cell multiple times. Try

```vb
Sub macro2()

    Const DVOFileName = "Book100.xlsx" ' test
   
    Dim wb As Workbook, cel As Range
    Dim F As String, s As String, n As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' formula for #N/A
    F = "=INDEX('[" & DVOFileName & "]WBSGL accounts'!$B:$B,MATCH(<ADDR>,'[" & _
        DVOFileName & "]WBSGL accounts'!$A:$A,0))"

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("R:R")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        For Each cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If cel.Row > 1 Then ' skip header
                s = Replace(F, "<ADDR>", cel.Offset(, -1).Address)
                'Debug.Print cel.Row, s
                cel.Formula = s
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows amended", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```